# Floating Point Exception in C++ Program

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
int num1, num2; // numerator                                                                                                                       
int den1, den2; // denominator                                                                                                                     

cin >> num1 >> den1 >> num2 >> den2;
if (den1<=0 || den2<=0)
cout << "problem could not be solved because denominator is zero and division by zero is        not defined" << endl;
else
if ((num1/den1)+(num2/den2))
cout << num1 << "/" << den1 << " + " << num2 << "/" << den2 << " = " << ((num1*den2)+  (den1*num2)) << "/" << (den1*den2) << endl;
else
  if ((num1/den1)-(num2/den2))
    cout << num1 << "/" << den1 << " - " << num2 << "/" << den2 << " = " <<    ((num1*den2)-(den1*num2)) << "/ " << (den1*den2) << endl;
else
  if ((num1/den1)*(num2/den2))
      cout << num1 << "/" << den1 << " * " << num2 << "/" << den2 << " = " <<     (num1*num2) << "/ " << (den1*den2) << endl;
    else
      if ((num1/den1)/(num2/den2) && num2 != 0)
        cout << num1 << "/" << den1 << " * " << num2 << "/" << den2 << " = " << (num1*den2) << "/ " << (den1*num2) << endl;
      else
        if ((num1/den1)/(num2/den2) && num2==0)
          cout << num1 << "/" << den1 << " * " << num2 << "/" << den2 << " could not be   solved because division by zero is not defined" << endl;\

 return 0;
 }
```

Hey guys I keep getting a floating exception when I run this program. I really can't figure out what the problem is. Help is extremely appreciated.

Comment: 1. In which line you are getting the exception? 2. What are the input values that is causing the exception?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is on these lines:

```
  if ((num1/den1)/(num2/den2) && num2 != 0)
    cout << num1 << "/" << den1 << " * " << num2 << "/" << den2 << " = " << (num1*den2) << "/ " << (den1*num2) << endl;
  else
    if ((num1/den1)/(num2/den2) && num2==0)
      cout << num1 << "/" << den1 << " * " << num2 << "/" << den2 << " could not be   solved because division by zero is not defined" << endl;\
```

The arguments to `&&` are processed left-to-right. So if `num2` is `zero`, you'll try to do the division before you test `num2 != 0`; so you need to perform the zero test first. You also need to test whether `num2/den2` is zero, not just `num2`, because the division could round down to zero even if `num2` is not zero.

```
  if (num2/den2 != 0 && (num1/den1)/(num2/den2))
    cout << num1 << "/" << den1 << " * " << num2 << "/" << den2 << " = " << (num1*den2) << "/ " << (den1*num2) << endl;
  else
    cout << num1 << "/" << den1 << " * " << num2 << "/" << den2 << " could not be   solved because division by zero is not defined" << endl;
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar. I did fix what you told me to. However, my outputs are still not correct. I was wondering what would be the best way to separate the "/" operator from fractions in the if statements. I think the "/" operator being in the if statements is messing up my output, since my output statements do not even use the "/" operator. It only uses the num1, num2, den1, and den2 values. EDIT: I've tried making the "/" from the input a string literal so it doesn't act as an operator, the program will simply recognize it from the input file, but I have no idea how to implement it.

Comment: I can't figure out what your program is supposed to be doing, so I don't know what the "correct" output is. It's just grade school arithmetic, write what you want. I notice that the `cout` line has `*` where the `if` line has `/`, you should fix that.

Comment: Whoops, I forgot to include the sample output. 3/5   +  1/5
12/10     -      1/3
-42/5*1/2
7/4   /  0/5
11/2 + 6/4


3/5 + 1/5 = 20/25
12/10 - 1/3 = 26/30
-42/5 * 1/2 = -42/10 = -4 2/10
7/4 / 0/5 could not be solved because division by zero is not defined
11/2 + 6/4 = 56/8 = 7 I don't know how to format this, but the idea of the program is to solve arithmetic problems dealing with fractions from an input file.

Comment: I'll try my best to explain what I'm trying to do. I'm supposed to run my program using an input file by i/o redirection. The input file will have a series of arithmetic problems (such as in my previous comment). What I'm trying to do is ignore the "/" operator in the input file and use only the num1, num2, den1, and de2 values. For example, with the arithmetic problem 3/5 + 1/5, I only want the 3, 5, 1, and 5 values to matter, not the "/" operator. Sorry if this is really confusing.

Comment: Your `cin` line is all wrong, since it expects the input to be just a sequence of numbers. You have no code to skip over the punctuation. This is completely unrelated to the floating point exception, and I'm not going to try to figure out how to fix it.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your time and helping me identify the problem.